# add column to one table based on values and conditions from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in a sql database. One, called, "results" consists of columns "type", "age", "01", "02", reporting the results of some tests (called '01' and '02') for some individuals described by attributes such as type and age. For example, table 'results' can look like:

```
| type |  age  |  01  |  02  |
------------------------------
    1      25     15     32
    1      45     23     65
    0      38     42     15
    0      21     54     22
```

The other table is called "refs" and consists of columns "test", "type", "age_lower", "age_upper", "mark_lower", "mark_upper". This table reports for each test in "test" (which can be either '01' or '02') and for each type in "type" (either 0 or 1), the lower and upper values ('mark_lower' and 'mark_upper') that the result of the test listed in "test" can get depending on the age group defined by the interval [age_lower, age_upper] as defined by the columns "age_lower", "age_upper". For example, table 'refs' can look like:

```
| test |  type  |  age_lower  |  age_upper  | mark_lower | mark_upper |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    01      0         20            30           10           20
    01      0         31            60           15           25
    01      1         20            30           11           22
    01      1         31            60           16           25
    02      0         20            30           20           40
    02      0         31            60           28           49
    02      1         20            30           22           42
    02      1         31            60           27           48
```

Now, how can I add (and select from) to the table "results" the right values of "mark_lower", "mark_upper" listed in the table "refs" corresponding to the different tests 01/02 and the appropriate age group and type, to obtain some like:

```
|type| age | 01 | 02 |mark_lower_01|mark_upper_01|mark_lower_02|mark_upper_02| 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  1    25    15   32       11             22          22            42
  1    45    23   65       16             25          27            48
  0    38    42   15       15             25          28            49
  0    21    54   22       10             20          20            40
```

Comment: What database - SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.?

Comment: It is MS SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this. One way is to join the [01] and [02] rows separately and then join the results together. The complete approach using your data is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cab5a/18

Sample data:

```
create table results (type int, age int, [01] int, [02] int);
create table refs (test int, type int, age_lower int, age_upper int, mark_lower int, mark_upper int); 

insert into results (type, age, [01], [02]) values
    (1,      25,     15,     32),
    (1,      45,     23,     65),
    (0,      38,     42,     15),
    (0,      21,     54,     22);
    
insert into refs (test, type, age_lower, age_upper, mark_lower, mark_upper) values
    (01,      0,         20,            30,           10,           20),
    (01,      0,         31,            60,           15,           25),
    (01,      1,         20,            30,           11,           22),
    (01,      1,         31,            60,           16,           25),
    (02,      0,         20,            30,           20,           40),
    (02,      0,         31,            60,           28,           49),
    (02,      1,         20,            30,           22,           42),
    (02,      1,         31,            60,           27,           48);
```

Solution using separate joins and a final join:

```
with a as
(
select rs.*, rf.test, rf.mark_lower, rf.mark_upper from results rs
left join refs rf
       on rs.type = rf.type
      and rs.age between rf.age_lower and rf.age_upper
      and rf.test = 1
), b as
(
select rs.*, rf.test, rf.mark_lower, rf.mark_upper from results rs
left join refs rf
       on rs.type = rf.type
      and rs.age between rf.age_lower and rf.age_upper
      and rf.test = 2
)
select a.type, a.age, a.[01], a.[02],
       a.mark_lower as mark_lower_01,
       a.mark_upper as mark_upper_01,
       b.mark_lower as mark_lower_02,
       b.mark_upper as mark_upper_02
from a
inner join b 
        on a.type = b.type 
       and a.age = b.age
;
```